# How to get all the columns in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anyone please tell me how can I get all the column names used in a database table in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- c.getColumnName(0)

access cursor property 0,1,2 pass as many column u have

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways i can think of:

```
PRAGMA table_info(yourTable)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable LIMIT 0
```

To get all tables:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```